# Lose the File Name in a URL but keep the query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can someone explain how I can lose the filename of a page but keep the query string intact? See the example situation below:

I have a blog list that's at
- www.example.com/tips-and-articles/ *(tips-and-articles.php)*

I have categories currently at
- www.example.com/tips-and-articles/article *(category.php)*

I have posts currently at
- www.example.com/tips-and-articles/article/here-is-an-article *(post.php)*

What I'm having difficulty with is removing the 'tips-and-articles' to just show the category and/or the post title, see below.

I want to have the following path to the category:
- www.example.com/article

I want to have the following path to the post:
- www.example.com/article/here-is-an-article

Below is my htaccess file currently, if I remove the 'tips-and-articles' I get an error.

```
RewriteRule ^tips-and-articles/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /post.php/?category=$1&post=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^tips-and-articles/([^/]+) /category.php/?category=$1 [QSA]   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: that what QSA means, QueryStringAppended (something like that) Add it to your last line `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: What error do you get? 404 not found? 500 server error? Anything else?

Comment: Sorry, I get "Internal Server Error" when I try to lose the 'tips-and-articles'.